# Swift Sending a cookie with an URL Request to get past Cookie Authentification

Tags: ios, swift, cookies

I'm trying to get HTML data from a website using swift to parse some tournament-results within an iPhone app.
However if I'm trying to access the site inside the code I get redirected to a page where normally you have to accept cookies.

I know that this cookie is stored in the HTTPCookieStorage but I can't seem to find a way to send it with my URLRequest. No matter what I do I always get the contents of the cookie-site instead of the page I'm trying to get.

Here is my approach:

```
let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies! as [HTTPCookie]
    var cookie = [HTTPCookie]()
    
    for i in cookies {
        if i.domain == "www.turnier.de" {
            cookie.append(i)
        }
    }
    
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookie, for: URL(string: "https://www.turnier.de/sport/winners.aspx?id=44325544-0A05-4330-BC8D-114AB3ECD25D"), mainDocumentURL: URL(string: "https://www.turnier.de/sport/winners.aspx?id=44325544-0A05-4330-BC8D-114AB3ECD25D"))
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.turnier.de/sport/winners.aspx?id=44325544-0A05-4330-BC8D-114AB3ECD25D")!)
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print(responseString)
    }
    
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Check this package: https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup

Comment: That’s what I’m using after I get the HTML. Problem is: If I call this page from code it sends me to a page where I have to accept cookies first. As if I’m a first time visitor to this page.